# How to Correct If Else Statement

Tags: java, if-statement, joptionpane

I'm Having a problem on my program, I'm Using if-else statement

In my program I'm trying to count the vowels and consonants on a String. I already know how to do it, my problem is i want to add an "error" message that if the user inputs a non-string it will show the error box.

"Try to run the program, The user will input a "String" and if the user press "Sort" it will
count the vowels and consonant. What i need is if the user will not enter a "String" example is double or int ...etc as long as it is not a string it will show a Error box.

```
/**
 *
 * @author Patrick
 */

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;
public class VowelandConsonant extends JFrame{
    private JLabel stringl, resultl,resultl1;
    private JTextField stringtf, resulttf,resulttf1;
    private JButton cb,eb;
    private CButtonHandler cHandler;
    private EButtonHandler eHandler;



public VowelandConsonant(){

    stringl=new JLabel("Enter String:",SwingConstants.CENTER);
    resultl=new JLabel("Vowel:",SwingConstants.CENTER);
    resultl1=new JLabel("Consonants:",SwingConstants.CENTER);

    stringtf=new JTextField(10);
    resulttf=new JTextField(10);
    resulttf1=new JTextField(10);

        eb=new JButton("Exit");
        eHandler= new EButtonHandler();
        eb.addActionListener(eHandler);

        cb=new JButton("Sort");
        cHandler= new CButtonHandler();
        cb.addActionListener(cHandler);


        setTitle("Vowels and Consonants");
        Container p=getContentPane();
        p.setLayout(new GridLayout(7,2));

        p.add(stringl);
        p.add(stringtf);
        p.add(resultl);
        p.add(resulttf);
        p.add(resultl1);
        p.add(resulttf1);
        p.add(cb);
        p.add(eb);

        setSize(500,400);
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}
         private class CButtonHandler implements ActionListener{
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){


                String string1;

                string1 = stringtf.getText();
                string1 = string1.toLowerCase();
                int vowels = 0;
                int consonants = 0;
                for (String retval: string1.split(" ")){
                     for (int i = 0; i < retval.length(); i++)
                {
                        char ch = retval.charAt(i);
                        if (ch == 'a' || ch == 'e' || ch == 'i' || ch == 'o' || ch == 'u')
                        {
                                vowels++;
                        }
                        else if(!string1.equals(string1)){
                            String a="Not a String Please try again ^_^";
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,a,"ERROR",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                        }

                        else 
                        { 
                                consonants++;
                        }



                }
            resulttf.setText(""+vowels);
            resulttf1.setText(""+consonants);
         vowels=0;
         consonants=0;
      }


            }
         }

            private class EButtonHandler implements ActionListener{
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                System.exit(0);
            }}
            public static void main(String[]args){
                VowelandConsonant a=new VowelandConsonant();
            }}
```

Comment: How do you define a 'non-string'?

Comment: What is in stringtf?

Comment: specify some input and required outputs scenarios

Comment: Non-string = int,double ...etc

Comment: One way would be to toss your code in a `try-catch` block and try to parse the String. If it's not numbers, an Exception would be thrown. You can then print out a message with `System.err.println();` What about special characters, such as `&*$%`?

Comment: !string1.equals(string1) I like that :-)

Comment: You are checking if `string1` is equal to itself which it will always be

Comment: @PatrickLouisFerrer Check out my answer I think it is what you are looking for...

Comment: ahah Sorry for that. I'm only a beginner in GUI :D anyways thanks alot for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you try like this;

```
   for (String retval: string1.split(" ")){
          if(!retval.matches("[a-zA-Z]+")){
                  String a="Not a String Please try again ^_^";
                  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,a,"ERROR",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }
           for (int i = 0; i < retval.length(); i++)
            {
                    char ch = retval.charAt(i);
                    if (ch == 'a' || ch == 'e' || ch == 'i' || ch == 'o' || ch == 'u')
                    {
                            vowels++;
                    } else 
                    { 
                            consonants++;
                    }

            }
    }
```

Check non-strings like :

```
                else if(!retval.matches("[a-zA-Z]+")){
                    String a="Not a String Please try again ^_^";
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,a,"ERROR",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could first check if it's a letter by the char code:

```
if(((int)ch >= 65 && (int)ch <= 90) || ((int)ch >= 97 && (int)ch <= 122))
{
    if (ch == 'a' || ch == 'e' || ch == 'i' || ch == 'o' || ch == 'u' || ch == 'A' || ch == 'E' || ch == 'I' || ch == 'O' || ch == 'U')
    {
         vowels++;
    }
    else
    {
        consonants++;
    }
}
else
{
   String a="Not a String Please try again ^_^";
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,a,"ERROR",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
}
```

This will check if it is A-Z or a-z if it is then check if it's a vowel or consonant.

Answer (score 0):

`string1` is defined as a String so it's always be a String

What you want to do is validate the user input with a regex. You only want to allow alphabetical characters but no digits

```
if (string1.matches("[a-zA-Z]+")) {
    //good input
}
else {
    //bad input
}
```

You can allow spaces by using regex [a-zA-Z]*